# Copy data frrom the output of an SQL query in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi-7

I have an SQL select query that extracts the "FirstName" field of a specific record. The output of running the query is a unique string.
I wish to copy this string( the First name) into the caption of a label. How can I do that in Delphi?

Comment: How are you executing the query to begin with? Which database component/library are you using? Please show the code you are having difficulty with

Comment: There are lots of existing questions here about getting data from SQL queries in Delphi. There is also a tutorial in the documentation about database programming with Delphi. Have you done any research (including basic web searches) before asking here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your Query Object is **Qry**:

```
 Label1.Caption := Qry.FieldByName('FirstName').AsString;
```